# Trello procedure to list cards then organize them into new groups and assign as a task

Tags: trello

Q re organizing carts
I want 5 people to generate a list of 15 or 20 cards and group them

Example

make a grocery list of 15 items to buy like apples and toilet paper then
group them into similar categories like fruit, dairy, paper products then
prioritize  the groups [list] for example in start to finish purchase order then
ask 5 different people to do homework on categories [lists]

Can you suggest a way to do this kind of listing, grouping prioritizing activity?

Answer (score 2):

There's no formal way to group cards (besides lists, of course).

I think checklists might be a good solution for this. You could add multiple checklists to a card ("Fruit", "Dairy", "Paper Products"), then sort them vertically by priority. Alternatively, you could have multiple cards ("Fruit", "Dairy", "Paper Products"), then a single checklist on each.

Comment: (Note: I work on the Trello team.)

Comment: you no longer need to say you work on the Trello team to every question you answer. It's in your profile.